# Generate Frontdoor URL for a scratch org in shell

Tags: salesforcedx, scratch-org, jq

In my shell script to create a scratch org I also need another command to actually login to that org. To simplify this I want to use [Frontdoor JSP](https://help.salesforce.com/s/articleView?id=000332032&type=1) and the [SFDX Auth URL](https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.sfdx_cli_reference.meta/sfdx_cli_reference/cli_reference_auth_sfdxurl.htm).

I was successful using jq to get this

```
force://PlatformCLI::5Aep8611MDY00my....pHYQ==@crazy-innovation-9274-dev-ed.cs94.my.salesforce.com"
```

but need this:

```
https://crazy-innovation-9274-dev-ed.cs94.my.salesforce.com/secur/frontdoor.jsp?sid=5Aep8611MDY00my....pHYQ==
```

I'm not a `sed` or `grep` expert. Maybe I can even get what I want without them?!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I could construct the URL using

```
INSTANCE="$(sfdx force:org:display --verbose --json | jq -r '.result.instanceUrl')"
SID="$(sfdx force:org:display --verbose --json | jq -r '.result.accessToken')"
URL=$INSTANCE/secur/frontdoor.jsp?sid=$SID
robot --variable AUTH_URL:$URL functional-tests.robot
```

Comment: This will certainly work. Check out my answer for a more concise approach using force:org:open's -r flag

Answer (score 3):

You can get this URL with the `force:org:open` command and the `-r` flag, eg:

```
> sfdx force:org:open -r -u MyScratchOrgAlias
```

https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.sfdx_cli_reference.meta/sfdx_cli_reference/cli_reference_force_org.htm#cli_reference_force_org_open

Another helpful flag that can be used with that command and flag is `-p` which can specify the relative path that should open.

Use `--json` if you need to use the response in a script, eg Powershell:

```
$URL = ((sfdx force:org:open -r -u MyScratchOrgAlias --json) | ConvertFrom-Json).result.url
```